# How do you create a custom event handler in Java?

Tags: java, listener, eventhandler

For the past few days, I've been trying to figure out how to create my own event in Java. I want to be able to use it like this:

```java
public class main {
    public void onTimeChange(MinuteChangeEvent event) {
        //do whatever when MinuteChangeEvent fires
    }
}
```

Basically, the method `onTimeChange` gets executed whenever `MinuteChangeEvent` fires. But how would I create that `MinuteChangeEvent` event, and how would I tell it when to fire?

For this, I would also need to have my class running at all times. How would I do that? Because normally, it just executes once, and that's it. If everything is right, what should happen is: Whatever is inside of that `onTimeChange` method gets executed every minute, which is when `MinuteChangeEvent` happens, and the class should be running until manually stopped.

I haven't been able to find anything on how to create a custom listener like that, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Are you using AWT, Swing, JavaFX or any other Java graphics library and which Java version? I think these would be helpful details.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. Anyway I am sending a snippet. Like user79161 mentioned in his comment please add more details to the question.

```
public class TestClass{
 
   public static void main(String args[]) {

        MinuteChangeEvent event = new MinuteChangeEvent();
        try {
           event.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
   
   public static void onTimeChange(MinuteChangeEvent event){
       System.out.println(String.format("Event fired %s time(s)", 
                                                 event.getCounter()));
       if(event.getCounter() >= 5){
           event.setStopped(true);
       }
   }

   static class MinuteChangeEvent implements Runnable{

       private int counter = 0;
       private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;
       private boolean stopped = false;

       @Override
       public void run() {
           counter++;
           if(!stopped)
              onTimeChange(this);
           else
              stop();
       }

       void start() throws Exception{
           executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
           executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
       }

       private void stop(){
           if (executorService != null)
              executorService.shutdown();
       }

       int getCounter(){
           return counter;
       }

       public void setStopped(boolean stopped) {
           this.stopped = stopped;
       }

       public boolean isStopped() {
           return stopped;
       }
   }


}
```